# Php array into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops, foreach

Have found examples, but nothing that works with what I'm trying to.

Have a very simple array of 'text'. I want to replace the text in the below javascript using a for each statement. Could someone point me in the right direction to replace the "text: 'Design'" items with my array?

```
$text= array("Display", "Training", "Separate");
var $treeData = [
        {
            text: 'Design',
            tags: ['40%'],
            href: '#parent3'
        },
        {
            text: 'Coding',
            tags: ['60%'],
            href: '#parent4'
        },
        {
            text: 'Marketing',
            href: '#parent5'
        }
    ];
```

Comment: convert to a php array first (via `json_decode($treeData, true)`), then iterate over that array and exchange the data with the corresponding array-item of $text - (I'm assuming $treeData is actually a string, right?)

Comment: Mind showing me how to do this with the above example?

Comment: Can you post the link where you go this example ?

Comment: I can't post a link - it's on a testing server

Comment: Can anyone answer, pretty please??